# new dynamic tools analysis for C-code

Tags: c, dynamic, analysis, for-loop

Could somebody tell me wich new dynamic tools analysis for C-code are there like valdgrind?

Answer (score 2):

Have a peek at [Fenris](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/fenris/whatis.shtml). Maybe not a valgrind replacement, but still very cool :) In fact, nearly all the tools [Michal Zalewski](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/) creates are really....creative (sorry).

Answer (score 2):

Here are two that you could look into:
[Splint](http://www.splint.org/) and 
[Frama-C](http://frama-c.cea.fr/) ( Frama-C is a static tool not dynamic )

Comment: Frama-C isn't dynamic analysis.  I don't Splint is, either.

Comment: "Splint is a tool for statically checking C programs for security vulnerabilities and coding mistakes."

Comment: "The Frama-C static analyzers assist you in various source-code-related activities, from the navigation through unfamiliar projects up to the certification of critical software. "